# how to load de-normalised data using hazelcast?

Tags: analytics, hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast for in memory data grid. We want to extend it for analytic using in memory computation.I have few question regarding this

1. Which data structure to use ? (I do not have primary key as de-normalize table and have a huge data )
2. If IMap the only option then can we use composite key or dummy key which should have support for index and predicate?
3. This is not the right use case i.e Hazelcast can not used for analytics?

Comment: IMap is the correct choice if the data is truly huge, too big to fit on one process. Can you expand more on what kind of processing you have in mind -- is it when the data changes, or static analysis ?

Comment: @NeilStevenson : Static analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate random keys based on `UUID::randomUUID` or you can create composite keys. Indexes can be created over values and keys (for keys use the magic keyword `__key#` and add the property of the key you're interested in.

Predicates use the same keyword if you're looking to run it against a composite key property, otherwise just query as you expect it from any other data.

Comment: If i have created IMap<Long,List<CustomPOJO>> .. will predicate and index work on the List  and how can i load table from database using loader which should load data on different node parallely?